# Проблема применения стилей при загрузке страницы CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Скорее всего это не сильная проблема, но возможно её можно решить, если да то помогите советом:

Представим что я хочу создать кнопки которые меняют размер текста и записывают все в `localStorage`.

Позже я прописываю чекер который будет отлавливать значение и менять размер текста.

Сложность в том что когда подгружает страница сначала она загружает CSS документ, а потом меняет значение через JS и в этом случае на несколько сотен миллисекунд я вижу как текст который становится сначала `16px`, а потом меняется на тот который мне нужен.

Возможно ли как-то исправить эту ситуацию и сделать более быстрое применение размера?

Если решение есть на jQuery, то прощу его не трогать, интересно понять на чистом JS.

Comment: Пробовали установку `font-size` из `localstorage` указывать в теге `script` перед подключением `css`?

Comment: Точно, даже не пришло в голову об этом. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае наиболее оптимальное, с точки зрения конечного пользователя, решение это сделать так что бы он не видел эти краткосрочные изменения размеров кнопки.

С точки зрения разработчика, на первый взгляд, это может показаться не очень удобно, но стратегия предложенная ниже определенно заслуживает внимания если Вы стремиться к качественному UI и UX.

Поскольку я не до конца знаю/понимаю Ваши специфику и задачи то соответственно просто оставлю это здесь, а стоит оно того или нет решать Вам.

Стратегия:

Перед закрывающими тегом `</head>` разместите скрипт, который срабатывает во время загрузки страницы. Он должен обращаться к корневому элементу (`body` в JS или `html, body` в jQuery) и делать его `opacity` моментально равным 0. А через несколько секунд (если воспользоваться таймером) или по любому другому хуку/тригеру верните значение обратно к 1, когда кнопка будет уже "правильного" размера.

Comment: Спасибо, придумал немного другое решение но основанное на этом же алгоритме.